# .jsp if else with <%@include file = .html> interaction

Tags: java, html, jsp

demo url:
`http://192.168.0.222/english/product_0207_sec.jsp?pid=en_1-02`
`http://192.168.0.222/english/product_0207_sec.jsp?pid=en_999`

inside .jsp file, the `<try>` part can extract different data in the same html page,
**how can I make the if else work with `<%@include file = .html>`**

---

- tried .jsp if else present with different include file  (in line 55 to 62)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"   %>
<%@include file="/include/gds_include.jsp"      %>

<jsp:useBean class="com.gds.DBconnect" id="dbHelper" scope="page" />

<%@include file="01_product_categories_detail.html"%>

<%

String id = request.getParameter("pid");

try {
    

    dbHelper.setConnection(77);
    
    dbHelper.setStatementIndex(0);
    dbHelper.setPreparedStatement("select * from webpage where p_id = '"+id+"'");
    dbHelper.exePreparedStatement();
    resultSet = dbHelper.getSqlResultArray();
    
    if(resultSet != null) {
        

        for(int i=0; i<resultSet.length; i++) {
            
            out.print("<tr><td>" );
            out.print("<h1>" + resultSet[i][2] + "</h1>"); 
            out.print( resultSet[i][6]);
            
        }
        
    
    }
    
}   
catch(Exception ex) {

    out.print("error message：" + ex);

}
finally {
    
    dbHelper.doFinalize();

}

%>

</html>

<%@include file="02_product_categories_detail.html"%>


<%
      String id = request.getParameter("pid");

      if(pid != "en_1-01")
          out.println(" <%@include file="footer_A.html"%> ");
      else if (pid == "en_1-02")
          out.println(" <%@include file="footer_B.html"%> ");
%>
```

so that this .jsp can deal with much more scenario, please give me a hand

---

- updated tried code_02

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"   %>
<%@include file="/include/gds_include.jsp"      %>

<jsp:useBean class="com.gds.DBconnect" id="dbHelper" scope="page" />


<%@include file="01_product_categories_detail.html"%>

<%

String id = request.getParameter("pid");

try {
    

    dbHelper.setConnection(77);
    
    dbHelper.setStatementIndex(0);
    dbHelper.setPreparedStatement("select * from webpage where p_id = '"+id+"'");
    dbHelper.exePreparedStatement();
    resultSet = dbHelper.getSqlResultArray();
    
    if(resultSet != null) {
        

        for(int i=0; i<resultSet.length; i++) {
            
            out.print("<tr><td>" );
            out.print("<h1>" + resultSet[i][2] + "</h1>"); 
            out.print( resultSet[i][6]);
            
        }
        
    
    }
    
}   
catch(Exception ex) {

    out.print("錯誤訊息：" + ex);

}
finally {
    
    dbHelper.doFinalize();

}

%>




<%
      String id = request.getParameter("pid");

      if(!id.equals("en_1-01"))  {
%>
    <%@include file="02_product_categories_detail.html"%>
<%
    }   else if (id.equals("en_1-02")) {
%>      
     <%@include file="microchip_product_categories_detail.html"%>
<%
    }
%>

</html>
```

- error message

```
Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [58] in the jsp file: [/english/product_0207_sec.jsp]
Duplicate local variable id
55: 
56: 
57: <%
58:       String id = request.getParameter("pid");
59: 
60:       if(!id.equals("en_1-01"))  {
61: %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:509)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:397)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

the `try { }` part works fine before, so the error occur on the if else statement (I guess)

Comment: `</html>` is close tag, end of one html page. Why do you put the content you want to append after `</html>`?

Comment: I was tried to put `<%@include file="02_product_categories_detail.html"%>` before `</html> ` was work, I though that was fine. I will correct it no worries, that I just learn jsp for about few days cause I want it feature, and also that why my question seems a bit simple

Comment: My fault, I didn't notice the rest of the code...Answer has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

UPDATE:

(1) REMOVE `String id = request.getParameter("pid");`

(2) String comparisons must use `equals`, not `==`.

```
<%
      if(!id.equals("en_1-01"))  {
%>
    <%@include file="footer_A.html"%>
<%
    }   else if (id.equals("en_1-02")) {
%>      
     <%@include file="footer_B.html"%>
<%
    }
%>
```

Comment: I just tried ur suggestion, there still get some error occur that update in post question, pls take a look

Comment: My fault, I didn't notice the rest of the code...Answer has been updated.

Comment: i just post the updated tried code_02, cause showed `Duplicate local variable id` so I didn't put the `String id = request.getParameter("pid");` in the first tried

Comment: remove line 58, remove `String id = request.getParameter("pid");`